# Regex for line containing one or more spaces or dashes

Tags: grep

I got .txt file with city names, each in separate line. Some of them are few words with one or multiple spaces or words connected with '-'. I need to create bash command which will echo those lines out. Currently I'm using *cat* piped with *grep* but I can't get both spaces and dash into one search and I had problems with checking for multiple spaces.

print lines with dash:
`cat file.txt | grep ".*-.*"`

print lines with spaces:
`cat file.txt | grep ".*\s.*"`

tho when I try to do:
`cat file.txt | grep ".*\s+.*"`
I get nothing.

Thanks for help

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
grep -E -- ' |\-' file.txt
```

---

**Explanation:**

- `-E`: to interpret patterns as extended regular expressions
- `--`: to signify the end of command options
- `' |\-'`: the line contains either a space or a dash

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that I need -E for regex

Comment: @flis00 Well, you do not need `-E` that badly, you can use a more efficient pattern than an alternation based pattern here, even with the default POSIX BRE.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, ``'[ \-]'`` that would work.

Comment: I believe it [should be this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244615/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly address your question, but is too much to put in a comment.

You don't need the `.*` in your patterns.  `.*` at the beginning or end of a pattern is useless, because it means "0 or more of any character" and so will always match.

These lines are all identical:

```
cat file.txt | grep ".*-.*"
cat file.txt | grep "-.*"
cat file.txt | grep "-"
```

Plus you don't need to cat and pipe:

```
grep "-" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

When `grep` pattern matches, the default action is to print the whole line, so `.*` in all your patterns are redundant, you may delete them. Also, you don't have to use `cat file |` as you may specify the file to `grep` directly after pattern, i.e. `grep 'pattern' file.txt`.

Here are some more details:

- `grep ".*-.*"` = `grep -- "-"` - returns any lines having a `-` char (`--` singals the end of options, the next thing is the pattern)
- `grep ".*\s.*"`  = `grep "\s"` - matches and returns lines containing a whitespace char (only GNU `grep`)
- `grep ".*\s+.*"` = `grep "\s+"` - returns line containing a whitespace followed with a literal `+` char (since you are using POSIX BRE regex here the unescaped `+` matches a literal plus symbol).

You want

```sh
grep "[[:space:]-]" file.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://#!/bin/bash%20s=%27abc%20-%20def%20ghi%20jkl%20mno%27%20grep%20%27%5B%5B:space:%5D-%5D%27%20%3C%3C%3C):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='abc - def
ghi
jkl mno'
grep '[[:space:]-]' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
abc - def
jkl mno
```

The `[[:space:]-]` POSIX BRE and ERE (enabled with `-E` option) compliant pattern matches either any whitespace (with the `[:space:]` POSIX character class) or  a hyphen.

Note that `[\s-]` won't work since `\s` inside a bracket expression is not treated as a regex escape sequence but as a mere `\` or `s`.